# How to scrape a table but 'not a table' from a page, using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

Humble greetings and welcome to anyone willing to spend time here. I shall introduce myself as a very green student of data science and also python. This thread is meant to gain insight from rather more fortunate minds capable of deeper understanding within the realm of python.

[image: the table im trying to scrape]

As we can see, the value for each row itself could be found easily on the page inspection. But it seems that they all are using the same class name. As for now, i'm afraid i couldnt even find the right keyword to search for any working method in google.

These are the codes that i've tried. They dont work and embaressing, but i have to show it anyway. Ive tried fiddling by adding .content, .text, find, find_all, but i understand that my failure lies at even deeper fundamental core.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import writer
import pandas as pd

url= 'https://m4.mobilelegends.com/stats'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
lists = soup.find('div', class_="m4-team-stats-scroll")

with open('m4stats_team.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = writer(f)
    header = ['Team', 'Win Rate', 'Average KDA', 'Average Kills', 'average Deaths', 'Average Assists', 'Average Game Time', 'Average Lord Kills', 'Average Tortoise Kills', 'Average Towers Destroy', 'First Blood Rate', 'Hero Pool']
    thewriter.writerow(header)

    for list in lists:
        team = list.find_all('p', class_="h3 pl-5 whitespace-nowrap hidden xl:block")
        awr = list.find_all('p', class_="h4")
        akda = list.find('p', class_="h4").text
        akill = list.find('p', class_="h4").text
        adeath = list.find('p', class_="h4").text
        aassist = list.find('p', class_="h4").text
        atime = list.find('p', class_="h4").text
        aalord = list.find('p', class_="h4").text
        atortoise = list.find('p', class_="h4").text
        atower = list.find('p', class_="h4").text
        firstblood = list.find('p', class_="h4").text
        hrpool = list.find('p', class_="h4").text


        info = [team, awr, akda, akill, adeath, aassist, atime, aalord, atortoise, atower, firstblood, hrpool]
        thewriter.writerow(info)

pd.read_csv('m4stats_team.csv').head()
```

What am i expecting:
Any kind of insight. Whether if it's clue, keyword, code snippet, i do appreciate and mostfully thankful for any kind of guidance. I am not asking for somehow getting the complete scrapped CSV, as i couldve done it manually. At these point i want to be able to do basic webscraping myself.

Comment: just change 1674043547673 to timestamp now in this link https://m4.mobilelegends.com/data/version/240/teams.csv?v=1674043547673

Comment: im sorry. how did you manage to find this data source?

Comment: chrome dev tools, network tab

Comment: oh i see how you get there. from my browser i could also use inspect element and find any related csv from the network tab also. for this insight i humbly thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over rows in the table and its items.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('https://m4.mobilelegends.com/stats')
page.raise_for_status()

page = BeautifulSoup(page.content)

table = page.find("div", class_="m4-team-stats-scroll")

with open("table.csv", "w") as file:
    for row in table.find_all("div", class_="m4-team-stats"):
        items = row.find_all("div", class_="col-span-1")
        # write into file in csv format, use map to extract text from items
        file.write(",".join(map(lambda item: item.text, items)) + "\n")
```

Display output:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("table.csv")

print(df)

# Outputs:
"""
      Team ↓Win Rate  ...  ↓First Blood Rate  ↓Hero pool
0     echo     72.0%  ...              48.0%          37
1      rrq     60.9%  ...              60.9%          37
2       tv     60.0%  ...              60.0%          29
3     fcon     55.0%  ...              85.0%          32
4      inc     53.3%  ...              26.7%          31
5     onic     52.9%  ...              47.1%          39
6     blck     52.2%  ...              47.8%          31
7   rrq-br     46.2%  ...              30.8%          32
8      thq     45.5%  ...              63.6%          27
9      s11     42.9%  ...              28.6%          26
10     tdk     37.5%  ...              62.5%          24
11      ot     28.6%  ...              28.6%          21
12     mvg     20.0%  ...              20.0%          15
13  rsg-sg     20.0%  ...              60.0%          17
14    burn      0.0%  ...              20.0%          21
15     mdh      0.0%  ...              40.0%          18

[16 rows x 12 columns]
"""
```

Comment: this code works very well for me while also enlighten me to what should be done from this case

- i was wrong at choosing which parameter and class to fetch the value
- i shouldve use comma separator and lambda and add manual line break to make sure the recorder text becomes proper CSV format
- as addition, i trid without using raise status and add encoding='utf-8' to make it work on my machine

thank you very much for the lesson. may your journey be filled with success along the path.

Comment: sorry im verry much new to any coding environment including stack overflow. i have accepted your answer by clicking the check mark icon.